# docker running in vmware gets x509 error

Tags: docker, vmware-player

I have installed docker into vmware player (windows host, ubuntu guest) and can run the simple hello world verification test but when I run any other docker images I get the following error:

```
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/[image-path]: 
  tls: failed to parse certificate from server: x509: 
  RSA modulus is not a positive number
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
Windows 7 host
Ubuntu 14.04 guest
docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d
vmware player, version 7.1.2 build-2780323
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, the following is how this problem was fixed:

1. Update the guest OS

   sudo apt-get update
2. Get new version of docker

   curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
3. Restart the guest OS